# Unusual output from using split()

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm reading from a file that has the following format:
name : symptoms : causes : treatments : rate : prognosis

There are a total of 21 entries but when I try to read from the file and use .split(":");, the output changes each time but is always along the lines of: [Ljava.lang.String;@614951ff. I'm guessing it's the pointer or memory address but I want the String value. I'm not getting any exceptions though so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. The purpose of the method is to read the file and split into an array using the delimiter for the given file row selected.

```
public String[] readCancer(int row) {
    cancers = new String[22];
    FileInputStream fis;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String eachCancer;
    String[] splitCancer = null;
    int j = 0;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myData);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        input = new Scanner(br);
        while(input.hasNext() && j < 23) {
            cancers[j++] = input.nextLine();
        }
        eachCancer = cancers[row].toString();
        splitCancer = eachCancer.split(":");
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem with file input");
    } finally {
        try {
            if(br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem closing the file");
        }
    }
    return splitCancer;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the sample i/p and o/p and what you are getting ?

Comment: can you also post the code which is invoking this method to see how it's using the returned String[]. Because stuff like [LString... is printed when you try to treat the String[] as a String.

Comment: Use Arrays.toString(splitCancer) to display it

Comment: @Raghunandan Do you need to escape a `:`?

Comment: I don't think so @squiguy ;)

Comment: is : considered a special character in java? I thought so. If i am wrong pls correct me.

Comment: @noob the file is created before the user does anything. Ultimately, it will be a GUI where they can search through by certain values, such as name, causes, etc... . For now though, I'm working just on the output from file and all I get is [Ljava.lang.String;@614951ff, where the part after the @ changes.

Comment: If you try to print an array just using `System.out.println()` , it calls the `Object` class `toString()` method and the address gets printed .To print the contents of the array , you need to do something mentioned in the answers .

Comment: @DevBlanked I'm calling the method in a main method                                                public static void main(String[] args) {  
        CancerGUI _gui = new CancerGUI();
        String[] resultCancer;
        resultCancer = _gui.readCancer(1);
        System.out.println(resultCancer);

    }

Comment: @cucko-oooo As giorashc has suggested use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultCancer)). Issue is you are trying to print the String[] by the looks of it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the string array, you should [use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitCancer));
```

Because when you print `splitCancer` you'll get the address of the array and not the content of it.

Of course you can print the content in other ways:

```
for(String str : splitCancer) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what advantage Str.split("\\:")  will have over Str.split(":") ?

Comment: @noob I edited my answer, it was my fault. `:` should work without escaping it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun how would I go about returning splitCancer as a String[] because it seems to be treating it as a string even though I declared splitCancer as a String[]? I tried doing return Arrays.toString(splitCancer); but the compiler gives an error saying it requires a String[] but found String.

Comment: You don't return `Arrays.toString`.. Use it if you want to print the array.. If you want to **return** the array, you have to `return splitCancer;`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I have tried doing that and it doesn't seem to work that way I currently have it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There seems to be a logical error with cancers[j] = input.nextLine();

Answer (score 2):

To print the contents of array :

1) `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(splitCancer));`

2) `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitCancer));`

3) `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitCancer));`

Comment: I tried the 2nd option and it works beautifully for printing the data to the console! I need the method to return a string array. When I try using return Arrays.toString(splitCancer), it immediately flags a compiler error saying splitCancer is a String but I declared it as a String[] in the method. How can I get it to return the actual string content rather than the address since I have to further manipulate the data and it would be easiest if it were returned as a String[]?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(splitCancer)` will give us a `String`, your actual return statement `return splitCancer;` returns a `String[]` just that you cannot print the individual strings(elements) of the array using `System.out.println()` . If you just need to access the elements of the array , you can use indexes like `splitCancer[0]` shall give the first element of the array if it's length is at least 1 .

Comment: When I try something such as split[j] = "blah"; and return it, then there are no compile errors but when split[j] = cancers[j].split(":"); is assigned to cancers[j] = input.nextLine(); or cancers[j] = input.nextLine().toString();, then I keep getting compile errors of incompatible types.

Comment: I cannot help until u post the actual code with data . Excuse me 4 brevity , typed using my BB

Comment: the data, main method I'm using to test the method and most recent code attempt are in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990881/1767133

Comment: I think I was over-complicating it for myself and I just figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have the following:

```
public String[] readCancer() {
    cancers = new String[22];
    split = new String[22];
    FileInputStream fis;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String eachCancer;
    int j = 0;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myData);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        input = new Scanner(br);
        while(input.hasNext() && j < 23) {
            cancers[j] = input.nextLine().toString();
            //cancers[j] = input.nextLine();
            split[j] = cancers[j].split(":");
            //split[j] = "blah";    this line works
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem with file input");
    } finally {
        try {
            if(br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem closing the file");
        }
    }
    return split;
    //return split[j]; does not work
}
```

In my while loop, I keep getting compile errors saying it requires a String but found Stirng[] for split. When I try something simpler, such as split[j] = "blah";, there are no compile errors. I can return cancers perfectly but I need to split by the : delimiter and that seems to be something I cant get my head around. When I try return split[j], then I get another compile error saying it requires a String[] but found String. I've been at this for more than an hour, read through examples in my textbook and tutorials online for using split but it still isn't working. This is the only part of my program that I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pasting the entire file but it came a horrid block of text, so here are 2 lines from it. Each line has the same format but differing lengths:

The general format of the file is name : symptoms : causes : treatment : rate : prognosis

The rate is a String since it is unknown for some diseases and when it is known, the rate is not always out of 250,000. Sometimes it is out of 1,000,000 or 100,000, etc... .

acute promyelocytic leukemia : easy bruising, rapid internal bleeding, fatigue, anemia, frequent fever, infection, blood clots : PML and RARA genes : Medications, chemotherapy : 1 in 250,000 : Good

familial cylindromatosis : numerous skin tumours, ulcers, infection, impaired eyesight, hearing, smell, balance : CYLD gene : Surgery, chemotherapy : Unknown : Unknown

My most recent code attempt is at [Unusual output from using split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985150/unusual-output-from-using-split/15990042#15990042)

The 2 arrays of cancers and split are private String[] as field variables declared outside any of the methods. The variable myData is a private File also declared as a field variable outside any of the methods. I have checked and already verified the file path is correct.

The main method that calls the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    CancerGUI _gui = new CancerGUI();
    String[] resultCancer;
    resultCancer = _gui.readCancer();
    //System.out.println(resultCancer);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultCancer));
}
```

I am only calling it in the main method to test whether it correctly returns the String[]. Once it does, then I will call it in a different method that adds the data to a GUI (this part I am reasonably confident I know how to do and have examples from my instructor and textbook to follow).